# TFS check as default - overwrite writeable files and overwrite all files for get specific version

Tags: tfs, getlatest

How can TFS be configured to select by default the two checkboxes "Overwrite writeable files that are not checked out" and "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version" when doing a Get Specific Version?

I am using TFS 2013.  My real goal is to automate the process of right clicking a folder, selecting Advanced, and then clicking the two checkboxes.  I have created a keyboard shortcut to pull up the window for Get Specific version, but I also want to have the two checkboxes selected by default.  I do not want this scripted through the command line as I still want to have the window popped up and manually perform the final step to hit the Get button.  Ideally the whole process would work something like Alt-G to pull up the Get Specific Version window, and then manually hit the Get button to complete the action.

Answer (score 0):

There is not option to change this default setting. Even though you don't want to use command, it seems using command line is the only way to automate the process.

```
tf get-overwrite

tf get-force
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf(v=vs.120).aspx